# rqt topic monitor failled AttributeError cStringIO.StringO

Tags: ros, topic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello every body,

A problem with rqt and topic monitor shows up this morning after an update/upgrade of my system (ubunut 14.04 with ros-indigo)

Since that upgrade I can't monitor any topic without having this error message :

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1488390882.559023] bad callback: <bound method TopicInfo.message_callback of <rqt_topic.topic_info.TopicInfo object at 0x7fafac18d1d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 720, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_topic/topic_info.py", line 100, in message_callback
    self.sizes.append(buff.len)
AttributeError: 'cStringIO.StringO' object has no attribute 'len'
```

In addition :

- Topics are still operationals since I can visualise them with *rostopic echo*
- This error occur on many type of message (std_msgs/string, moveit...)
- This error occur regardless the publishing node

Does anyone have some clues ? Concerning me it's look like some python related file or configuration have been corrupted...

Thank by advance.

here below some system's information

**Python interpreter version  :** 2.7.6

**System information**

> Linux version 4.4.0-64-generic (buildd@lcy01-27) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ) #85~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 12:10:54 UTC 2017

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255923/rqt-topic-monitor-failled-attributeerror-cstringio.stringo/) by [adrienH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28141/adrienh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this happens many times, and I'm kind of sure that [this patch](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/pull/434) fixes it. It is/will be available in version 0.4.6 of `rqt_topic` (I just noticed that the [changelog gives more info](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/commit/a65df4c04600b2a3009001ce835cec283ab8f2b6#diff-00bab463ede5b38cea7f48e412c7887f) regarding this).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adrienH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28141/adrienh/) on 2017-03-01**:
thanks !!! I have just dowload the patch and run the folowing commande :

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo install
```

and it works again

Thanks again

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-01**:
It's up to you, but pedantically when building source you're advised to use catkin workspace (I can't find the best resource for this, but something like [this](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace)), instead of directly writing into the protected folders like `/opt`.

**Comment by [adrienH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28141/adrienh/) on 2017-03-02**:
To be more specific on what I've done (if someone want the full procedure),
I have created a new workspace  into witch I've cloned your link to the patch and then I have built it with this command :

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo install
```

hope it's more clear